# Making an Excel tab not print?

Tags: excel

Is there any way in Excel to make it so that a particular tab isn't included when you print the entire workbook? As in, Sheet1, Sheet2, and Sheet3 print, but not Sheet4.

So like when someone goes to File -> Print or whatever, and hit OK, etc, everything prints out except for a particular designated tab (which I assume I have to "hide from printing" somehow).

I'm sending this workout out to a bunch of people so I'm trying to avoid forcing them to enable/run macros and all that stuff. Is there just a property of a sheet somewhere like "exclude from print"?

Comment: How is your print prevention related to the macros? And would it be an option to exclude the sheet completely? --- My first thought would be to set the print area with a macro, and then remove it but that is untested.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin I have no idea the details. All I know is that I have a workbook that I am sending to a lot of people, but I need to make it so that if they print that workbook out, it excludes a particular tab. I'm saying that I don't think macros are the solution here because then I'd have to tell people "Well if you want to print it then you need to enable macros and maybe change security and this-and-that" when all they want to do is print the thing.

Answer (score 3):

These answers will require the use of macros.
Hide the sheet before printing.

```
 sheets("WorksheetToNotPrint").visible = xlSheetHidden 'or 0
```

or

```
 sheets("WorksheetToNotPrint").visible = xlSheetVeryHidden 'or 2
 'used if you don't want people to unhide the worksheet without knowing code
```

and

```
 sheets("WorksheetToNotPrint").visible = xlSheetVisible 'or -1
```

when done

another option is to print the sheets you want printed (may be useful if you only want a few sheets printed:

```
Sub Print_Specific_Sheets()
Sheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet4")).Select
ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Does this actually hide the sheet from sight? As in, if I open the workbook, I won't be able to physically see the tab unless I "unhide" it? Does this require macros enabled?

Comment: yes, this will hide it from sight, and would require a macro. I can't see a way to exclude a sheet from printing, unless you define a print area that has something like "this page intentionally left blank" in it.

Comment: Might want add info about: `Private Sub Workbook_BeforePrint(Cancel As Boolean)` event.

Comment: @PortlandRunner Are you saying that there's a way to run custom VBA code when someone goes through the default file -> print process?

Comment: Yes, but it's limited because there is no AfterPrint option to reset pages.  So you need to circumvent the print process.  You can get values from the print dialog and use them however.

Comment: What do you mean by "reset pages"?

Answer (score 1):

Actually the answer seems to be surprisingly simple.

If you hide the sheet, it will not be printed when you print the entire workbook.

You won't need a macro, just

1. right click on the sheet name
2. choose `hide`

If needed you or other users can unhide it as well.

Comment: If he is "sending this to a bunch of people" and doesn't want them to hassle with extra steps then I don't think this answer is what he is looking for because now the user has to remember to hide certain sheets.

Comment: @PortlandRunner The sheet can be hidden before the file is sent.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the `BeforePrint` event then you can alter what the built in print function can do.  The `BeforePrint` macro is inside 'ThisWorkbook' under 'Workbook'.

For example you can hide sheet 4 so it doesn't print like this:

```
Private Sub aWorkbook_BeforePrint(Cancel As Boolean)
    Sheets(4).Visible = xlSheetHidden
End Sub
```

---

The downside to this method is there is no `AfterPrint` method to unhide the sheets.  So you need to circumvent the print dialog.  There are several ways to do this but here is one very simplistic method.  (Note: This might not be a good solution if you have many other printing scenarios that you need to account for)

Here I am telling exactly what sheets to print (only sheet 1 and 4).  You can use names instead of numbers and you can even create a loop and look for variables to determine what sheets you want to print.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforePrint(Cancel As Boolean)
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    Sheets(Array("1", "4")).PrintOut , , 1

    Application.EnableEvents = True

    '//prevent the default print
    Cancel = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Just set the print area on the tab you don't want to print to a single blank Cell, This will mean that it will print a single blank page rather than the reams of data that I presume you are trying to avoid printing.

Answer (score 0):

To do this manually just select all the sheets you want to print by clicking on the first sheet tab label, then hold down the 'Shift' key and click on the last sheet tab label.   (If you have a large number of sheets use the small arrow keys to navigate)

If you need to unselect a sheet in the middle hold down the CTRL key and click that sheet.

Alternately you can hold the CTRL key and click on each sheet tab label.

The sheet colour will be white (with a gradient on the none active sheet) to show they have been selected.

WARNING:  When multiple sheets are selected any change on one will be repeated in the same cells on all of them.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to use VBA or hide the sheet, you could just set print area on an empty cell of the sheet you do not want to print.

The tab will still be printed but the result will be an empty sheet.

Answer (score 0):

### Using an easy Macro:

Just put this lines inside a new Macro, and replace the names of the sheets yo DO want to be printed:

```
Sheets(Array("Name_of_Sheet_1", "Name_of_Sheet_2")).Select
Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("PrintPreviewAndPrint")
```

Answer (score -1):

Why all the crazy coding?

Just click on the first tab you want to print and make it active.
Then hold down control, and click on each additional tab you want to print, excluding the tab, or tabs you don't want to print.
Then go to "file" and then "print" like you normally would. Make sure "print active sheets" is selected, then print.

It prints only the tabs you selected.
Simple, and no need to complicate things to ridiculous levels of unnecessary silliness.