# How to make a sheet not printable in XlsxWriter

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

With XlsxWriter I try to make one sheet not printable.
I don't want to hide it.

I tried to use `.print_area(None)` or `.print_area(0,-1,0,-1)` and `.print_area_range` without success.

```
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('noprint.xls')
worksheet0 = workbook.add_worksheet('Tableau')
worksheet0.write(0,0,'make noise')
worksheet1 = workbook.add_worksheet('feuille2')
worksheet1.write(1,1,'my tailor is rich')
worksheet1.print_area(0,0,0,0)
workbook.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this in Excel itself without writing VBA code that will temporarily hide the sheet, as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19863838/making-an-excel-tab-not-print) makes clear. I understand that you don't want to hide the sheet, but that is how Excel itself achieves the effect.

It follows that there is no way for `xlsxwriter` to do it.

Comment: Thank you very much. I stop my "quest".
so i change my point of view and create 2 Excel.
one for print and the other for analyse

Comment: @BSoldano If the answer worked for you please accept it.